# What is the difference between new Date().getTimezoneOffset() and new Date(string).getTimezoneOffset()?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, timezone-offset

I recently noticed that the values of these two are different on some dates.

For example, the output of both is the same for `04/01/2020` but different for `03/01/2020`.

```js
console.log(
  new Date("2020/03/01").getTimezoneOffset(), //-210
  new Date().getTimezoneOffset(),             //-270
);

console.log(
  new Date("2020/04/01").getTimezoneOffset(), //-270
  new Date().getTimezoneOffset(),             //-270
);
```

I did this test for all the months of this year and the result was:

- `2020/01/01` -> different
- `2020/02/01` -> different
- `2020/03/01` -> different
- `2020/04/01` -> same
- `2020/05/01` -> same
- `2020/06/01` -> same
- `2020/07/01` -> same
- `2020/08/01` -> same
- `2020/09/01` -> same
- `2020/10/01` -> different
- `2020/11/01` -> different
- `2020/12/01` -> different

Comment: Could just be [*DST*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset).

Comment: One returns the current local offset and the other the offset for the parsed string, which might be an invalid or unexpected date or a time when the host system's setting indicate a different offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getTimezoneOffset` function returns the offset from UTC for the local time zone that applies to the moment in time represented by the `Date` object instance you call it on.

- If you call it on `new Date()`, you're asking for the *current* offset, as the default constructor sets the `Date` object's timestamp to the current value, as also given by `Date.now()`.
- If you call it on `new Date(value)`, you're asking for the offset that applies to the moment in time represented by that value.

Time zone offsets are not fixed, but rather they are established by governments and can easily change.  One reason they change is due to daylight saving time (DST), which may or may not apply to a given time zone for part of the year.  Other reasons they might change is due to governmental policies around modifying the observance of DST, the start and stop dates or times of DST, or a change to the *standard* time offset.  Since these sorts of changes create historical differences, it is necessary to know which point in time you are asking about when you ask for the offset from UTC with `getTimezoneOffset`.

You can read more about this in the section titled *"Time Zone != Offset"* in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

One other thing - the format you provided for the string ("2020/03/01") is non-standard.  It may or may not be supported by a given JavaScript engine, but it is not part of the specification.  Instead, you should use either `"2020-03-01"` (if you mean midnight UTC on that date), or `"2020-03-01T00:00:00"` (if you mean midnight local time on that date).